# Significant figures

Tags: error-analysis

How to calculate [significant figures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures) of a number? I got confuse as the number 28600 has 3 significant figure instead of 5. Anyone can explain?

Comment: Have you read your textbook or the now-included Wikipedia link?

Comment: The number 28600 does not have any number of significant figures. It is an exact number. When you write a check for 28600 dollars, the bank will pay EXACTLY 28600 dollars or all hell breaks lose. When I order 28600 components from my electronics supplier, they will send me exactly 28600 components or I have a right to reject the shipment at their cost, which is why they have counting machines for this purpose. If you want to specify an accuracy for a number it's much better to do it explicitly like 28600+-1000.

Comment: More on [significant figures](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+significant+figures).

Answer (score -2):

The number of significant digits in 28600  depends on what the error in the measurement is. If sigma = 15 Then we can write 28600(15) and there are 5 significant digits. If sigma = 1800 then we can write 28600 +-1800 and there are 3 significant digits. If sigma = 25000 then we can write 2.9(25)x10^4 and there are 2 significant digits. Significant digits are the work of the devil and cause much confusion. Calculate the uncertainty first and then you can calculate how many significant digits there are.

Jack

Comment: OP doesn't mention anything about error here.

Comment: This is incorrect. 28600 has 3 significant digits regardless what the uncertainty is (unless it is an absolute number). If the uncertainty is (15), then writing it as 28600 is inappropriate *because* that has 3 sig digs. It should then be written as $2.8600\times10^4$, which has 5 sig digs.

Comment: @KyleKanos The question is tagged [tag:error-analysis].

Comment: If the error is large enough to affect the *fourth* digit, then the value only has *four* significant figures?

Comment: Is it correct to write “2.9(25)x10^4” if sigma = 25x10^**3**?

Answer (score -5):

It have **5 significant figures**, as the zeros are present on right hand side of a numbers .

Comment: Trailing zeros are generally regarded as [*insignificant*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures), so it should be 3, not 5.

Comment: @kyle According to text book I read should 5.

Comment: Either your textbook is wrong or you misread it; trailing zeros are not significant.

Comment: Well, in the usual convention trailing zeros *before* the radix are not significant, but those after the radix are.

Comment: I consider the number 28600 to be ambiguous with regard to significant figures.  That is why it is best to use scientific notation for such numbers, such as 2.86 x 10^4, which clearly has 3 significant figures.